# as.Date fails in R: 'character string is not in a standard unambiguous'

Tags: r, excel, date, statistics

I am working with data in `R` that I imported form `excel` format.

I have a column (`isas1_3b`) in the dataframe (`LPAv1.1.1`) which is in the `character` format. Upon importing, the dates have changed from the format dd/mm/yy, to days (e.g., 41268).

I have tried to convert this as below:

```
as.Date(LPAv1.1.1$isas1_3b, origin = "1899-12-30")
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
>   4. stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")
>   3. charToDate(x)
>   2. as.Date.character(LPAv1.1.1$isas1_3b, origin = "1899-12-30")
>   1. as.Date(LPAv1.1.1$isas1_3b, origin = "1899-12-30")

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. After numerous searches, the above conversion is what was recommended.

I should also add, that there are two other date columns in the original `excel` document. But they have both been read in as `'POSIXct''POSIXt'`.

Other info that may be relevant:

```
macOS 13.13.3 R 3.3.3 RStudio 1.1.419
```

Can someone please help resolve this issue... I am assuming it is something that I am doing. Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: Your `isas1_3b` column is not numeric, it's a character column currently. Convert it using `as.numeric` first and then try again.

Answer (score 3):

As `thelatemail` rightly pointed out, the column with the days information must be in numeric format.

```
d <- 41268

as.Date(d, origin = "1899-12-30")
#[1] "2012-12-25"
```

On your dataset, this will fix it:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(LPAv1.1.1, isas1_3b = as.Date(as.numeric(isas1_3b), 
                                     origin = "1899-12-30"))
```

Comment: Thanks both for your speedy responses. `Deepak Rajendran`, thanks for the code. I ran it but it still shows the class as "character" and has not make the expected changes. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated. No matter what I do, the `as.numeric` function seems to not be able to convert it to the format I want...?

Comment: @Atanas Janackovski Could you post a sample of your dataset, please?

Comment: I'd love to. What is the best way to do this? I'm really sorry, I am very new to `R` and `stackoverflow`---thank you in advance for your patience.

Comment: You can edit your original post above using the `edit` button, and paste the sample dataframe.

Comment: Thanks Deepak. I think I figured it out. The class was not consistent within the column/vector. There was a mix of dates, strings, and four digit numbers. Once I corrected these, it worked as expected. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The variable class was not consistent within the column/vector. There was a mix of dates, strings, and four digit numbers. Once I corrected these, it worked as expected. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How did you import it from excel? Is it possible to adjust the import method so it imports it the way you are expecting?

Importing the data from excel with the package "xlsx" gives you two options read.xlsx which will detect/guess the class type based on the data in that column, or read.xlsx2 where you have to/get to set the class types manually with the colClasses option. (more info here: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/r-xlsx-package-a-quick-start-guide-to-manipulate-excel-files-in-r)

Another useful option is XLConnect.

A possible downside of both of these packages is they rely on Java to do the work of importing, so you must have Java installed for these to work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing cell format for the dates in Excel to Date Type "2014-03-24" and saving the file as CSV (MS-DOS) (*csv) before loading into R.